# @FXML-annotated components coming from different FXML files resulting in NPE

Tags: java, javafx

I have two FXML files. The first describes the first pane to show up, which contains a tab pane, a menu and a menu item, which is supposed to open a new tab in the tab pane and draw a new set of Nodes in it.
This is the code:

```
public class Main extends Application {

private Pane mainRoot;
private Pane secondaryRoot;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        mainRoot = (Pane) ResourceLoader
                .load("MainFXML.fxml");

        secondaryRoot = (Pane) ResourceLoader.load(("SecondaryFXML.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainRoot);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

        thisMain = this;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

private static Main thisMain;

public static Main getMain() {
    return thisMain;
}
public Pane getSecondaryRootPane() {
    return secondaryRoot;
}
```

Then I have a single controller associated to both FXML files. So, it has the tab pane as a FXML-annotated field. Furthermore, it handles the click event on the menu item, which is the one creating the new tab:

```
public class GUIController {
@FXML
private TabPane tabPane;

public void newTabRequest(Event e) {
    // create the new tab
    Tab newTab = new Tab("New tab");

    // set the content of the tab to the previously loaded pane
    newTab.setContent(Main.getMain().getSecondaryRootPane());

    // add the new tab to the tab pane and focus on it
    tabPane.getTabs().add(newTab);
    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(newTab);

    initializeComboBoxValues(); // HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM
}}
```

Last line of the controller invokes a method, whose code is as follow:

```
private void initializeComboBoxValues() {
    myComboBox.getItems().add(MyEnum.myEnumValue1);
    myComboBox.getItems().add(MyEnum.myEnumValue2);
}
```

and I have a field @FXML ComboBox having the same name as the corresponding component declared in the FXML and that I am trying to fill up with values.
The issue is that myComboBox results null. Where am I wrong? Where am I designing it wrong?

If it can help, I want to make this point: I created and added a test button in the new tab. The event associated to this button invokes the same initializeComboBoxValues method. Well, that works (given I remove its invocation from the newTabRequest handler, so to avoid the NPE).

Comment: What is `ResourceLoader` and why don't you use `FXMLLoader`?

Comment: It's just a class I created that uses FXMLLoader: its load method is return FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource(filePath));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every time you use `FXMLLoader`, you create a new controller. Since you don't do anything to connect both controllers, every controller has only the `@FXML` annotated fields set, that were in it's own `Pane` at the time it was inflated.

You'll have to establish some kind of communication between both controllers to get it working.

You can get the controller from the `FXMLLoader`, if you use a instance of the `FXMLLoader` and a non-static load function, e.g. like this (don't reuse a `FXMLLoader` to load a second fxml file):

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
// be sure to use a non-static load method, like load(InputStream)
secondaryRoot = loader.load(getClass().getResourceAsStream("SecondaryFXML.fxml"));
FXMLDocumentController secondaryController = loader.getController(); // Change type to your controller type here
```

You can then add a method to your controller that allows you to pass the other controller to the controller. That way you can access the fields from the other controller.

*I strongly advise you to create different controller classes for both layouts. Otherwise that only adds confusion.*

Comment: Thanks, the fact that a new controller is instantiated is eye-opening. Then yes, different controller classes are appropriate. Rather than coupling the controllers directly,  though, I will create a catalogue of controllers to query in order to access other controller services.