# Can't set text on label or text class because of NullPointerException

Tags: java, text, label

```
public void setBtnAction(ActionEvent event) {
    String leagueNameString = nameFld.getText();

    if ((leagueNameString == null) || (leagueNameString == "")) {
        nameFld.setPromptText("Enter value league name");
    } else {
        CoreAppFXMLController cp = new CoreAppFXMLController();
        cp.nameOfTheLeague.setText(leagueNameString);
    }
}
```

}

I tried with both, text and label, but none of them works. 
nameOfTheLeague is protected in CoreAppFXMLController class. It returns me NullPointerException. id's are ok in fxml.

Comment: Not again: `leagueNameString == ""`. Check [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java). Also your code uses `leagueNameString`, not `nameOfTheLeague`.

Comment: oh dear.. I changed to (leagueNameString.trim().equals("")) but stills returns NullPointerException. nameOfTheLeague is label, and leagueNameString is String from textfield.

Comment: Post code which will actually [let us reproduce your problem](http://sscce.org/). Otherwise we can only guess what is wrong with it. Also `cp` is local variable of `setBtnAction` method. Is it possible that you wanted to initialize `cp` which would be your class field?

Comment: Nope, I just need cp to access nameOfTheLeague. I have; protected Label nameOfTheLeague. I could use; protected static Label nameOfTheLeague; and then CoreAppFXMLController.nameOfTheLeague.setText(nameOfTheLeague)..  Anyway it doesn't work.

Comment: Ok here it is.. If you need anything else let me know.. in this class http://pastebin.com/AK5BCjKw I have my main stage and within, a menu. In that menu I have set league name option and then this one pops up http://pastebin.com/SKNrVirj . Its simple settext on click but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0):

The way you create `CoreAppFXMLController`, you just invoke the constructor. **Nothing else will be done**. That means that **no nodes are created**, since no `fxml` file is loaded and of course `cp.nameOfTheLeague` is never assigned.

You have to use a `FXMLLoader` to create `Node`s **and** controller from a `fxml` file and make the assignments for the `Node`s with ids.

If you don't know how to use a `FXMLLoader` to get the controller, it's demonstrated in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24716026/2991525

Also, if you compare `String`s use `string1.equals(string2)`, not `string1 == string2`.

Comment: I dont need any fxml loaded. It is already loaded at the start. I just need to change the label of main fxml file which controller is  CoreAppFXMLController. I have protected Label nameOfTheLeague; and in my other controller I have a method that checks for input and sets the label. I will try with ur suggestion.